# Where is Sophos anti-virus in Ubuntu?

Tags: antivirus

I installed Sophos anti-virus by following the instructions here: 
https://www.fosslinux.com/2852/how-to-install-sophos-antivirus-software-in-ubuntu.htm 
Where can I find the application now? 
It seems to be totally invisible. I am not sure whether it has been installed or not.

PS. I am new to Linux and I run Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. I tried ClamTk before, but it did not work. In that case, the application opened, but the buttons had no function.

Also I noticed that there is a folder left in `/home/user/.clamtk`, although I removed ClamTk yesterday. Can I manually remove it?

Comment: Did you follow all the steps ? And read the guide all the way to the end ? You will find the answer there !

Comment: Thank you! I am running `savscan /` now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you changed defaults, your sophos files should be under `/opt/sophos-av` .

Quote from manual:

> How to check if on-access scanning is active?
>
> Enter the following command in the ‘Terminal’.
>
> ```
> /opt/sophos-av/bin/savdstatus
> ```
>
> How to start on-access scanning?
>
> Use the following command to enable and start the on-access scanning,
>   if found that service is inactive.
>
> ```
> /opt/sophos-av/bin/savdctl enable
>
> /etc/init.d/sav-protect start
> ```
>
> How to run an on-demand scan?
>
> Simply enter the following command to start scanning your computer.
>
> ```
> savscan /
> ```

Comment: I entered the command `savscan /` and now, many hours later, it is still scanning.... I am in a dual boot system and from what I see it scans all hard drives. Although it cannot open all files (errno is 13).

Comment: If your /opt isn't on a dedicated partition, you could decide to put Sophos on /usr/local/sophos-av and adjust the lines below accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that I have to learn lots of new things in Ubuntu. First of all, I did not know how to open /opt. My initial question was more for finding out where is the app and how I can work with it. 
So, if I understand well, not all apps have GUI in Ubuntu. So, learning how to navigate with Terminal is essential. Is this correct?

Comment: Unfortunately, not all commands have GUI wizards (or not yet). `/opt` is just yet another folder (or directory in Ubuntuish). I am glad I could be of assistance to you, my friend. If there's anything more unknown, please ask here freely. The problem is that if you don't have an `/opt` dedicated partition, your Sophos AV will install in the same partition as your boot loader and kernel. You could try to post the result of `df -k` command in your terminal.